# Find unique number among 3n+1 numbers

Tags: algorithm

I have been asked this question in an interview.

> Given that, there are 3n+1 numbers. n of those numbers occur in triplets, only 1 occurs single time. How do we find the unique number in linear time i.e., O(n) ? The numbers are not sorted.

Note that, if there were 2n+1 numbers, n of which occur in pairs, we could just XOR all the numbers to find the unique one. The interviewer told me that it can be done by bit manipulation.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: what were you interviewing for?

Comment: what about memory limits and the range of numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Count the number of times that each bit occurs in the set of 3n+1 numbers.
2. Reduce each bit count modulo 3.
3. What is left is the bit pattern of the single number.

Oh, dreamzor (above) has beaten me to it.

Answer (score 8):

You can invent a 3nary XOR (call it `XOR3`) operation which operates in base 3 instead of base 2 and simply takes each 3nary digit modulo 3 (when usual `XOR` takes 2nary digit modulo 2).

Then, if you `XOR3` all the numbers (converting them to 3nary first) this way, you will be left with the unique number (in base 3 so you will need to convert it back).

The complexity is not exactly linear, though, because the conversions from/to base 3 require additional logarithmic time. However, if the range of numbers is constant then the conversion time is also constant.

Code on C++ (intentionally verbose):

```cpp
vector<int> to_base3(int num) {
  vector<int> base3;
  for (; num > 0; num /= 3) {
    base3.push_back(num % 3);
  }
  return base3;
}

int from_base3(const vector<int> &base3) {
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 0, three = 1; i < base3.size(); ++i, three *= 3) {
    num += base3[i] * three;
  }
  return num;
}

int find_unique(const vector<int> &a) {
  vector<int> unique_base3(20, 0); // up to 3^20
  for (int num : a) {
    vector<int> num_base3 = to_base3(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_base3.size(); ++i) {
      unique_base3[i] = (unique_base3[i] + num_base3[i]) % 3;
    }
  }

  int unique_num = from_base3(unique_base3);
  return unique_num;
}

int main() {
  vector<int> rands { 1287318, 172381, 5144, 566546, 7123 };
  vector<int> a;
  for (int r : rands) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      a.push_back(r);
    }
  }
  a.push_back(13371337); // unique number

  random_shuffle(a.begin(), a.end());

  int unique_num = find_unique(a);
  cout << unique_num << endl;
}
```

Comment: why the conversion to 3nary number ? does it have any extra advantage over theorish's solution ?

Comment: @parvez_bai no, just the first idea that I came with because of simple analogy with binary/3nary XOR, his solution is indeed easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

```
byte [] oneCount = new byte [32];

int [] test = {1,2,3,1,5,2,9,9,3,1,2,3,9};

for (int n: test) {
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++) {
        if (((n >> bit) & 1) == 1) {
            oneCount[bit]++;
            oneCount[bit] = (byte)(oneCount[bit] % 3);
        }
    }
}

int result = 0;
int x = 1;

for (int bit = 0; bit < 32; bit++) {
    result += oneCount[bit] * x;
    x = x << 1;
}

System.out.print(result);
```

Looks like while I was coding, others gave the main idea